# Use a Variable in a Function Without Passing as an Argument

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments

In python is there any way at all to get a function to use a variable and return it without passing it in as an argument?

Comment: Use `global` but it is not recommended

Comment: I tried that but it only works if you don't change the variable value and return it. Can you not modify any variables inside functions and return them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you ask **is** possible.  If a function doesn't re-bind (e.g, assign to) a name, but uses it, that name is taken as a *global* one, e.g:

```
def f():
    print(foo)

foo = 23
f()
```

will do what you ask.  However, it's a dubious idea already:  why not just `def f(foo):` and call `f(23)`, so much more direct and clearer?!

If the function needs to bind the name, it's even more dubious, even though the `global` statement allows it...:

```
def f():
    global foo
    print(foo)
    foo += 1

foo = 23
f()
print(foo)
```

Here, the **much** better alternative would be:

```
def f(foo):
    print(foo)
    foo += 1
    return foo

foo = f(23)
print(foo)
```

Same effect - much cleaner, better-maintainable, preferable structure.

**Why** are you looking for the inferior (though feasible) approach, when a better one is easier and cleaner...?!

Comment: I have player position variables, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz and I use them in most of my functions (and modify dx, dy, dz in many functions). It seems unnecessary to have to call these in and return them. So you cannot modify variables in functions and return them without passing them in?

Comment: @MattMaich why not encapsulate those variables in a single object, e.g. a dictionary, or as part of a `Player` class? Then you only have to pass one thing around.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alex Martelli pointed out, you *can*... but *should* you? That's the more relevant question, IMO.

I understand the *appeal* of what you're asking. It seems like it should *just be* good form because otherwise you'd have to pass the variables everywhere, which of course seems wasteful.

I won't presume to know how far along you are in your Python-Fu (I can only guess), but back when I was more of a beginner there were times when I had the same question you do now. Using `global` felt ugly (everyone said *so*), yet I had this irresistible urge to do exactly what you're asking. In the end, I went with passing variables in to functions.

**Why?**

Because it's a code smell. You may not see it, but there are good reasons to avoid it in the long run.

*However, there is a name for what you're asking*:

#### Classes

What you need are *instance* variables. Technically, it might just be a step away from your current situation. So, *you might be wondering*: Why such a fuss about it? After all, instance variables are widely accepted and global variables *seem* similar in nature. So what's the big problem with using global variables in regular functions?

The problem is mostly *conceptual*. Classes are designed for grouping related behaviour (functions) and state (player position variables) and have a wide array of functionality that goes along with it (which wouldn't otherwise be possible with only functions). Classes are also ***semantically significant***, in that they signal a clear intention in your mind and to future readers about the way the program is organized and the way it operates.

I won't go into much further detail other than to say this: You should probably reconsider your strategy because the road it leads to inevitably is this:

- 1) Increased coupling in your codebase
- 2) Undecipherable flow of execution
- 3) Debugging bonanza
- 4) **Spaghetti** code.

Right now, it may seem like an exaggeration. The point is you'd greatly benefit to learn how to organize your program in a way that makes sense, ***conceptually***, instead of using what currently requires the least amount of code or what seems intuitive to you *right now*. You may be working on a small application for all I know and with one only ***1 module***, so it might resemble the use of a single class.

The *worst* thing that can happen is you'll adopt bad coding practices. In the long run, this might hurt you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I guess I'll start learning some classes. I'm still going to reserve x,y,z as global variables though